# Save wall post data

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, mysql, html

Hi i have a partial website up as im having extreme difficultys trying to figure out how to save some information http://project.mcr00t.eu/ You can log into the site with any credentials atm there is no functionality for it atm, it will bring you to the users profile page which has a wall posting part to it, you can write on your wall similar to facebook.

The part im trying to get my head around is how to save that data so it stays on the wall im using asp and mysql? Can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save data in a web application into mysql you need to design database schema in mysql that will hold your data. Then you need to write code in your asp application that will connect to the mysql database with your schema and write data that you want to save in there. To access mysql from ASP you need mysql ODBC driver. Create an ODBC source that point to you mysql database and then use ADO as you would normally do for connecting to an ODBC source.

Comment: lol thanks but this is already done, its not what im asking. Im trying to figure out how to save the contents of divs in my wallposting system I already know how to save data to mysql. Just dont know how to access the contents of my html for forwarding to sql via the cs file.

Comment: Re-read your question =) This is what you asked. This is what I answered. Unless you can give more specific details it's very had to guess what is your problem it.